# System.js: material2 is not loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, systemjs

I'm starting a new angular2 project with [material2](https://github.com/angular/material2).

I've defined system.js to load the material2 modules but for some reason, they are not loaded and i can't use the material directives:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular2 playground</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <html-app>Loading...</html-app>
</body>

<!-- ES6-related imports -->
<script src="/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
<script>
    //configure system loader
    System.config({
        packages:{
            'dist':{
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            // The core package is required as a peerDependency for other components.
            'node_modules/@angular2-material/core': {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js',
                main: 'core.js'
            },
            'node_modules/@angular2-material/checkbox': {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js',
                main: 'checkbox.js'
            },
            'node_modules/@angular2-material/button': {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js',
                main: 'button.js'
            }
        }
    });

</script>
<script src="/node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js"></script>
<script>
    //bootstrap the Angular2 application
    System.import('dist/main.component').catch(console.log.bind(console));

</script>

</html>


//this gives me a regular button with no styling
<button md-icon-button>
   <i class="material-icons md-24">favorite</i>
</button>
```

I get no error in the console and on the network tab, i can see that no material module was loaded. here is my directory structure:

[image]

@angular2-material is under node_modules.

Comment: How are you trying to import the material packages within your code?  The `System.config({ packages :  ... })` only tells SystemJS where to look when you ask for a specific package.  If you are using examples you may be trying to do something like `import * as buttton '@angular2-material/button` which SystemJS wouldn't intrinsically know about.

Comment: @ArcSine - thanks, you're right, I really need to get used to working with TS and angular2 :). Do you know of any example of using material2? I couldn't find any on the web

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/988, as an example of mapping in a package from node_modules to systemjs.